# Flutter: (How) Can I have a PageView of widgets that each rely on Provider?

Tags: dependency-injection, flutter, mobx

I'm trying to design my app with [Providers](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) and [MobX "Stores"](https://mobx.pub/), and can't figure out a proper way to use Providers/Stores within widgets that may be included in a PageView.

I have a StatelessWidget "PlayerPage" which displays data from a single observable "Player" object from a "PlayerStore" which is provided inside the PlayerPage with Provider.of.

In some parts of my app, one PlayerPage is all there is, but in other parts, several PlayerPages are contained in a PageView supplied with a list of Players (from a "TeamStore").

Since the PageView builds a few PlayerPages at a time and I have the one PlayerStore containing a single Player at a time, this didn’t work.

I figured out a semi-workaround with setting PlayerStore’s Player in PageView’s "onPageChanged" rather than the "itemBuilder", but then I get MobX messages about how “There are no observables detected in the builder function for Observer@(number)” (I assume from the built PlayerPages not shown) along with some other problems when jumping to a page, and I’m thinking there must be a better way to handle all of this…

Can someone please tell me where I’ve gone wrong (whether with PageViews or a deeper misunderstanding of Provider/MobX)?

```
class PlayerPage extends StatelessWidget {

  const PlayerPage({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    PlayerStore playerStore = Provider.of<PlayerStore>(context);

    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Observer(
          builder: (_) =>
              SinglePlayerStatsDisplay(
                playerStore: playerStore,
              ),
        ),
        Observer(
          builder: (_) =>
              PlayerStatControls(
                playerStore: playerStore,
              ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

...

```
class PlayersPageViewState extends State<PlayersPageView> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: widget.startingIndex);
    widget.playerStore
    .setPlayer(widget.teamStore.players[widget.startingIndex]);
  }

  ...

    body: PageView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => PlayerPage(),
            itemCount: widget.teamStore.players.length,
            onPageChanged: (index) => widget.playerStore.setPlayer(widget.teamStore.players[index]),
            controller: _pageController,
          )

    ...
}
```

...

```
abstract class _PlayerStore implements Store {
  @observable
  Player player;

  @action
  setPlayer(Player newPlayer) => player = newPlayer;

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `Observer`, but doesn't observe anything.

```
Observer(
  builder: (_) =>
      SinglePlayerStatsDisplay(
        playerStore: playerStore,
      ),
),
```

While `playerStore` is observable, you are passing it *as is*. 
In that case, `Observer` is not needed at all and can be removed.

`Observer` would only be needed for something like:

```
Observer(
  builder: (_) => Text(playerStore.foo.toString()),
),
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I guess I overdid the Observers, as I wasn't sure exactly where I needed them. Removed those, and now am getting that "no observables detected" warning at a much lower rate" (I'm sure there's still another needless Observer or two to remove somewhere else). 

Regarding PageView, is that a good way to handle things (having a widget with provider of store and setting the store in onPageChanged)? 
And does it make sense using a TeamStore with ObservableList of Players and a PlayerStore with a single Player? 
Also, thank you for making the Provider library!

Comment: @Eddie I don't see anything wrong. Although the `provider.of` from `PlayerPage` could be moved to `SinglePlayerStatsDisplay`

Comment: I need help in a similar situation.. Can someone please take a look at this? Thanks in advance...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67923192/provider-state-management-for-pagecontroller-in-flutter